# Java Comparable for Generic Types

Tags: java, comparable

When trying to compare a generic type in the form

```
  Class<T> implements Comparable<T> {

      public int compareTo(T other){
        this.T < other
      } 
  }
```

does not work for me but when using

```
  Class<T extends Comparable<T>>{
     T.compareTo(other.T)
  }
```

does work.  I have been unable to deciper why I can't compare T directly using the first example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first example:

```
class Foo<T> implements Comparable<T> {
```

you're saying that `Foo` objects are comparable. In your second example:

```
class Foo<T extends Comparable<T>>{
```

you're saying that whatever `T`, is, it's comparable.

Then, in the body of your code, you try to compare things of type `T` -- in the first case, you have no guarantee that they're comparable, in the second, you do.

Answer (score 1):

I hope these two exmaples will cast some light on your problem:

```
class Foo<T> implements Comparable<T> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(T o) {
        // We don't know anything about T
        return hashCode() - o.hashCode();
    }
}

class Boo<T extends Comparable<? super T>> implements Comparable<T> {
    private T instance;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(T o) {
        // We know that T implements Comparable<? super T>
        return instance.compareTo(o);
    }
}
```

In first case with `Foo`, you don't know anything about type `T`, so you can't do much in your `compareTo()` method.

However, in `Boo`, `T` is required to implement `Comparable<? super T>` (if you don't know what [wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) are, just think there is simply `Comparable<T>`), so you can call `t.compareTo(anotherT)`. More about [bounded type parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html).

**EDIT:** (wildard explained)

Consider following code:

```
class Car implements Comparable<Car> { ... }
class SportCar extends Car { ... }
```

Now call `sportCar1.compareTo(SportCar2)` is perfectly legal. However, without the wildcard,
`Bar<SportCar>` is a cpompile error!

Why? Because `SportCar` *doesn't* implement `Comparable<SportCar>`. And you require `T` to implement `Comparable<T>`, and in this case `T` is `SportCar`.

But `SportCar` implements `Comparable<Car>` and `Car` is a supertype of `SportCar`. So you want to say something like "T can be compared to T or any supertype of T" (like in this case `SportCar` can be compared to any `Car`).

And that what the wildcard is for (among many other things). Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, why am I comparing to the super type of T (whatever that is) Comparable<? super T>